# Dollar sign with scales:: math_format (10^.x)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add dollar sign to log10-scaled axis ticks in ggplot2. There are out-of-box solutions for dollars and for log10, and I am struggling to put them together:

```
# this works
formatter <- scales::trans_format("log10", scales::math_format(10^.x))
```

Following example breaks:

```
# this breaks
formatter <- scales::trans_format("log10",
                     scales::math_format(paste("$", round(10^.x, 2),sep=' ')))


ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=price, x=color)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.25, fill='blue') +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = formatter
  )
```

This produces `$ round(10^x, 2)`.

On the other hand, if I assign the plot object to a variable, it produces following error:

```
bp_diamonds <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=price, x=color)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.25, fill='blue') +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = formatter
  ) 

 bp_diamonds

# Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :   polygon edge not found
```

Comment: Upon copy/passting your code, I get `<ScaleContinuousPosition>
 Range:  
 Limits:    0 --    1`

Comment: Are you interested in scales only or just want to get this format for ggplot2? p.s. I am getting the same output from running your code as @akrun.

Comment: The order you're applying functions is a problem. You won't be able to math-format or log-format something with a dollar sign in it. You should make the `paste0($, ...)` the outermost operation

Comment: Updated the code example. @Gregor: how would you use it in this case?